# WebDAV not working with Form Based Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication, webdav

I am really stuck with this and have tried everything to get this to work AND really need some help.

I have a Site Collection where users log in via the Default SP Login Page, when they log in and use the Open with Explorer or use the Map to Network Drive it doesn't work. The Open with Explorer shows a message that the site needs to be in a Trusted Zone, well the blunt answer there is - it already is! When mapping the drive it says Access Denied. However, the funny thing is though if you open a document from the browser as a hyperlink it will ask you login, as expected and it works! Further, if you choose the Remember Me checkbox in the login page, then everything works! However, we do not want to use the checkbox.

Can someone please help me as to why this is not working and how to fix it?

Comment: What OS and version of IE are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 64bit Enterprise and IE9 32bit

Comment: Service Pack 1 is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying this hotfix
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39849

Check to see if you have that installed - it was published to windows update so you may have it.  The KB article references IE10 specifically, but the update is for windows binaries, not IE.

You can try installing fiddler and reproducing the issue.  You should be able to see what credentials are being passed and how when you attempt to open in explorer view.  If it looks like it's trying to pass your NTLM token and immediately failing, then disable the "automatic logon" in the IE zone and try again.   Without the "remember log on" box being checked you should be forced to enter your credentials to connect.

Comment: Thanks applying the fix did the check without changing the IE settings